# How can i add ninepatch image as background of an instance of "Table" class (libgdx)

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx to make a small game. For the backgrounds in my game, I would like to use one generic image and stretch it as per the dimensions required. To do this, I am using "NinePatch" images.

However, when i set a ninepatch image as the background of an instance of "Table" class of libgdx, libgdx adds the padding on all the four sides? The padding is equal to the left,right,top,bottom offsets that i specify while making ninepatch from an image. How can i do away with this padding?

Here is the code that i have written..

```
public class myTable extends Table{
  public myTable(NinePatch ninePatchImage){
    this.width = 50;
    this.height = 100;
    this.setBackground(ninePatchImage);
  }
}
```

The problem is the setBackground() method of the "Table" class of libgdx, which is adding the paddings.

How can i avoid this padding? Please note that i do need to have left,right,top,bottom offsets, because i have some styled corners !!

Any help would be very very useful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the behavior of the table improve or change if you use a regular (non-NinePatch) image?

Comment: Solved this by setting padding to 0 after applying background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It works for me.

```
table.getBackground().setLeftWidth(10);
table.getBackground().setRightWidth(10);
table.getBackground().setBottomHeight(10);
table.getBackground().setTopHeight(10);
```